# What are these tiny gray bugs that I find outside near wood?

Tags: identification, pests

I have been finding these tiny gray bugs all over my outside, typically near a wood pile or on wooden furniture. They are so small i can't really give much as far identifying marks, so I hope my pictures are enough...

At first I was worried they were termites, but looking at pictures of those online, it doesn't seem to be. The only thing that came close is either a silverfish, which seem larger than what I have; or some type of springtail. It says springtails are typically found inside and in high humidity places, but I am only finding them outside and while the humidity is higher this time of year I am finding them in "dry" spots (aforementioned wood piles) not damp parts of the house like a basement.

Location: Pittsburgh, PA, United States.

Close up picture with 5x zoom:
[image: close up 5x]

Close up picture with 2x zoom:
[image: close up 2x]

Close up picture with 1x zoom:

[image: close up 1x]

Picture of a group:
[[image: group photo4]